# Stripe Android error no suitable constructor

Tags: android, stripe-payments

When I am trying to build my project it is giving me an error.same below code is worked fine before updating android studio to 2.3.After updating it is giving me this error.I am using Stripe API version 2016-07-06.

**Code**

```
    Stripe stripe = new Stripe();
    stripe.createToken(card, publishableApiKey, new TokenCallback() {
      public void onSuccess(MediaSession.Token token) {
      // TODO: Send Token information to your backend to initiate a charge
      Log.d("StripeToken", "MediaSession.Token created: " + token.toString());
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MediaSession.Token created: " + token.toString(), //getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

**Error**

```
Error:(100, 13) error: no suitable constructor found for Stripe(no arguments)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(Context,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: Seems like your Striple constructor holding some parameters

Comment: what isn't clear in error message? class `Stripe` has no constructor without parameters. You have to pass something into parameters.

Comment: but same code worked for me before updating android studio

Comment: @satya no...this code will not compile even though you are not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `Context` argument to your `Stripe` object constructor. There is no more no-arg constructor for the `Stripe` object (that was the breaking change going from 2.1.0 -> 3.0.0).

It has nothing to do with your Android Studio upgrade - just the Stripe library upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

@mrmcduff is right.

Please find the correct way from their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) below.

```
    Stripe stripe = new Stripe(mContext, "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh");
stripe.createToken(
  card,
  new TokenCallback() {
    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
      // Send token to your server
    }
    public void onError(Exception error) {
      // Show localized error message
      Toast.makeText(getContext(),
        error.getLocalizedString(getContext()),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
      ).show();
    }
  }
)
```